# printing dictonary keys with javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using the below code to see dictionary `UserNames` values

```
 for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(UserNames)) {
                    console.log(`${key}:`);

                }
```

the result is good. but on screen when coding

```
var thekey = ${key};                    
 document.getElementById("users").textContent = thekey.toString();
```

showing just 1 key. why?

Comment: Because every time you do this: `document.getElementById("users").textContent = thekey.toString()` you *overwrite the contents*, so it's only going to show the last thing you put it it. Change `=` to `+=`. Also there are no dictionaries in Javascript, you have objects and Maps and neither one has the exact same semantics as dictionaries in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're constantly overwriting the content of #users instead of adding to it. Here's what I mean.

```js
document.getElementById("users").textContent = "key1";
// At this point, #users contains "key1"

document.getElementById("users").textContent = "key2";
// At this point, #users contains "key2"
// This is because you set the content using =,
// which overwrites the previous content
```

If you want to append, use `+=` instead.

```js
document.getElementById("users").textContent = "key1";
// At this point, #users contains "key1"

document.getElementById("users").textContent += "key2";
// At this point, #users contains "key1key2"
// This is because you set the content using +=,
// which appends to the existing content
```